# without using iframe for lightbox popup form

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**This is my code:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example4/colorbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test").click(function () { //on clicking the link above
        $(this).colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"100%",scrolling:false});
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3>External Form</h3>
<a href="https://ss88.wufoo.com/forms/rmndx1a0zzpe4m/" id="test">Please fill out my form.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Now this is works fine, May i know, how to run this code for same output without using iframe?

Thanks in advance!!..

Answer (score 0):

```
/ Using a selector:
$("#inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#myForm"});

// Using a jQuery object:
var $form = $("#myForm");
$("#inline").colorbox({inline:true, href:$form});
```

Or just make iframe false.

Details are given on their website. Colorbox.js